# Can anyone help me identify what's causing the Infinite Loop here?

Tags: c++, while-loop, infinite-loop

Running this program on a shell through WinSCP, I don't get an infinite loop until I add this while loop to the code:

```
#ifndef TERMINAL_HPP
#define TERMINAL_HPP

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include "filesystem.hpp"

class Terminal {
private:
    FileSystem fs;

public:
    Terminal() {}

    void run() {
        std::string command;
        std::vector<std::string> tokens;

        std::cout << "Welcome to the Terminal!\n";
        while (true) {
        std::cout << fs.pwd() << "$ ";
        std::getline(std::cin, command);

        if (command.substr(0, 4) == "mkdir") {
            std::string name = command.substr(5);
            std::cout << fs.mkdir(name) << std::endl;
        } else if (command.substr(0, 5) == "touch") {
            std::string name = command.substr(6);
            std::cout << fs.touch(name) << std::endl;
        } else if (command == "pwd") {
            std::cout << fs.pwd() << std::endl;
        } else if (command == "ls") {
            std::cout << fs.ls() << std::endl;
        } else if (command.substr(0, 2) == "cd") {
            std::string name = command.substr(3);
            std::cout << fs.cd(name) << std::endl;
        } else if (command.substr(0, 2) == "rm") {
            std::string name= command.substr(3);
            std::cout << fs.rm(name) << std::endl;
        } else if (command == "exit") {
            std::cout << "Exiting..." << std::endl;
            break;
        } else {
            std::cout << "Unknown command. Type 'help' for available commands." << std::endl;
        }
    }


    }
};



#endif /* TERMINAL_HPP */
```

For added reference, I'll include the FileSystem class as well:

```
#ifndef FILESYSTEM_HPP
#define FILESYSTEM_HPP

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include "node.hpp"

using namespace std;

class FileSystem {

private:
    Node *root;
    Node *currentDirectory;

    Node *findNode(std::string name) {
        std::vector<Node*> children = currentDirectory->getChildren();
        for (Node *node : children) {
            if (node->getName() == name) {
                return node;
            }
        } return nullptr;
    }

public:
    FileSystem() {
        root = new Node("/root", 'd');
        currentDirectory = root;
    }

    ~FileSystem(){
    vector<string> names;
    for(Node *node : root->getChildren()){
      names.push_back(node->getName());
    }
    for (string name : names) {
      root->removeChild(name);
    }
    delete root;
}


    std::string mkdir(std::string name) {
        if (name.empty()) {
            return "mkdir: missing operand";
        }
        if (findNode(name)) {
            return "Error: " + name + " exists";
        }
        Node *node = new Node(name, 'd');
        currentDirectory->addChild(node);
        return "directory " + name + " created successfully";
    }

    std::string touch(std::string name) {
        if (name.empty()) {
            return "touch: missing operand";
        }
        if (findNode(name)) {
            return "Error: " + name + " exists";
        }
        Node *node = new Node(name, 'f');
        currentDirectory->addChild(node);
        return "file " + name + " created successfully";
    }

    std::string pwd() {
    std::vector<std::string> pathStack;
    Node *node = currentDirectory;
    while (node != root) {
        pathStack.push_back(node->getName());
        node = node->getParent();
    }
    std::string path = "/root/";
    while (!pathStack.empty()) {
        path += pathStack.back() + "/";
        pathStack.pop_back();
    }
    path.pop_back();
    return path;
}

    std::string ls() {
    std::string result = "";
    std::vector<Node*> children = currentDirectory->getChildren();
    for (Node *node : children) {
        if (node->getType() == 'f') {
            result += "f " + node->getName() + "\n";
        } else if (node->getType() == 'd') {
            result += "d " + node->getName() + "\n";
        }
    }
    return result;
}

    std::string rm(std::string name) {
    if (name.empty()) {
      return "rm: missing operand";
    }
    Node *node = findNode(name);
    if (node == nullptr) {
      return "No such file or directory";
    }
    if (node->getType() == 'd') {
      // delete directory and all of its contents
      std::vector<Node*> children = node->getChildren();
      for (Node *child : children) {
        rm(child->getName());
      }
    }
    node->getParent()->removeChild(name);
    delete node;
    return name + " removed successfully";
}


    std::string mv(std::string from, std::string to) {
    if (from.empty() || to.empty()) {
      return "mv: missing operand";
    }
    Node *fromNode = findNode(from);
    if (!fromNode) {
      return "file not found";
    }
    Node *toNode = findNode(to);
    if (toNode && fromNode->getType() != toNode->getType()) {
      return "mv: cannot overwrite '" + to + "' with '" + from + "': Different file type";
    }
    fromNode->getParent()->removeChild(from);
    fromNode->setName(to);
    if (toNode) {
      delete toNode;
    }
    currentDirectory->addChild(fromNode);
    return "file/dir renamed successfully";
  }


    std::string cd(std::string name) {
        if (name == "..") {
            if (currentDirectory == root) {
                return "can't change to directory ..";
            } else {
                currentDirectory = currentDirectory->getParent();
                return pwd();
            }
        } else {
            Node *node = findNode(name);
            if (node == nullptr) {
                return name + ": no such directory";
            } else if (node->getType() == 'f') {
                return name + ": is not a directory";
            } else {
                currentDirectory = node;
                return pwd();
            }
        }
    }

};

#endif
```

Every time I run ./main it displays "Welcome to the Terminal!" then freezes, seems like it's infinite looping and times out of the server shell. main runs fine with everything except the while loop, so I know it has to be something in the while loop.

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me.  Are you sure WinSCP provides a normal terminal environment?  You aren't checking for end-of-file, but that should produce an infinite series of errors.

Comment: Can you elaborate on *"Running this program on a shell through WinSCP"*?